# SSH authentication Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh, authentication, remote-access, ssh-keygen

I'm having problem when I try to connect to a remote server using ssh with the following command:

> ssh -vvv -l *user* *hostname* -p XXXX

I get the following result:

> OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /home/johannys/.ssh/config
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
>   debug1: Connecting to xxxx.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port xxxx.
>   debug1: Connection established.
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u1
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
>   debug1: Authenticating to xxxxx.com:2020 as 'user'
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
>   debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
>   debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
>   debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>   debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256   SHA256:VYlY/MrjfxzISurmLT3AD2ZaXgSsSPEDhesAPjSGLBY
>   debug1: Host '[xxxxx.com]:xxxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /home/johannys/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>   debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
>   debug1: Will attempt key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_rsa RSA   SHA256:aRPCgKDIJBNXISKuLrJnj17+jdv27OSfaUP3TPaQG2o agent
>   debug1: Will attempt key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_dsa
>   debug1: Will attempt key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>   debug1: Will attempt key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_ed25519 
>   debug1: Will attempt key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_xmss
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
>   debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>   debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
>   debug1: No valid Key exchange context
>   debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
>   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
>   No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
>   debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
>   No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering public key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_rsa RSA   SHA256:aRPCgKDIJBNXISKuLrJnj17+jdv27OSfaUP3TPaQG2o agent
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_dsa
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_ed25519
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/johannys/.ssh/id_xmss
>   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>   xxxxx.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

I have checked the file permissions and they seem to be okay:

> drwx------  2 johannys johannys   4096 out  8 10:47 .ssh
>   drwx------  2 johannys johannys 4096 out  8 10:47 .
>   drwxr-xr-x 22 johannys johannys 4096 out  8 11:50 ..
>   -rw-r--r--  1 johannys johannys  106 out  8 10:44 config
>   -rw-------  1 johannys johannys 1876 out  8 10:40 id_rsa
>   -rw-r--r--  1 johannys johannys  398 out  8 10:40 id_rsa.pub
>   -rw-r--r--  1 johannys johannys  444 out  8 10:47 known_hosts

On the server side, the auth.log reports:

> Oct  7 15:50:07 XXX sshd[18309]: Accepted publickey for XXX from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XXXX ssh2: RSA SHA256:0
>   Oct  7 15:50:07 XXX sshd[18309]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user XXX by (uid=0)
>   Oct  7 15:51:09 xxx sshd[18566]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for bacefebb.virtua.com.br [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

What might be wrong ?

Comment: do you have restriction to host, like `from=` in authorized_keys file?

Comment: Not! Actually I don't have authorized_keys yet!

Comment: Then probably this is the source of the issue :)